# 2 Data frame multiplication with one Transform

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe

```
ddd = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,1],'b' : [1,1,1],'c' : [1,1,1],'d' : [1,1,1],'e' : [1,1,1] })
fff = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [3,3,3]})
```

I want this output

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  3  3  3  1
1  1  3  3  3  1
2  1  3  3  3  1
```

I want to run a loop and Transpose my fff dataframe and multiply with ddd dataframe on b,c,d column

I tried this

```
for i in range(3):
    print(fff.a.T.multiply(ddd.iloc[i,1:4]))
```

Getting all null values

Comment: @ Shubham Sharma It works Thanks, I Just have to change .multiply() with * and Transpose (T) with tolist() and it works. Please Answer so  I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do:

```
ddd[['b', 'c', 'd']] *= fff['a'].tolist()
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  3  3  3  1
1  1  3  3  3  1
2  1  3  3  3  1
```